# the return value of system("path/a.out")

Tags: c, function, return-value

I had this idea to try to use the return value of system in a conditional statement in another program , here's what I came up with :

the first program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(void)
{
    char ans;
    scanf("%c" , &ans);
    if(ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;    
}
```

the second program (the one calling system()):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(void)
{
    if(system("/home/M435TR0x/a.out") == 1)
        printf("you answered yes\n");
    else
        printf("you answered no");
}
```

but this didn't work because the program always returns `you answered no` when I used printf to see the return value of system if was `256` when the program should return `1` (the 0 works fine) when I replaced `return 1` with `return 2` I got `510` .
I don't know what's going on their but it reminds me of the number of combinations possible in an byte in the case `return 1` and the number of combinations in 9bits in `return 2` , it's like the program is doing  `(255 << (i - 1)) + 1` where `i` is the return value and `i > 0`.

does any one knows what's really happening there ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The situation is implementation defined. C11 7.22.4.8/3 (`system`) says:

> If the argument is not a null pointer, and the `system` function does return, it returns an implementation-defined value.

So, what's going on on your system? I'm assuming you're using Linux, and `system` is implemented in terms of `fork`, `exec` and `wait`. The last one, `wait`, returns a *status*, which is a 16-bit integer, and which tells you whether the process exited normally or via a signal, and what the return value or the signal were, respectively. To access those, use the macros in `man 2 wait` on the return value of `system`.

```
#include <stdlib.h.>    // for "system"

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int n = system(cmd);
```

- `WIFEXITED(n)` is true if the process exited normally; if so, `WEXITSTATUS(n)` tells you the return value.
- `WIFSIGNALED(n)` is true if the process ended because of a signal; if so, `WTERMSIG(n)` is the signal number.

Side note: on my Linux, `man 3 system` gives the wrong information that the return value is already processed with `WEXITSTATUS`, while the more recent `info system` correctly states that the return value is the status from the underlying `wait`.

Comment: Yeah man 3 system realy confused me but I think that they talk about when `system` calls system commands. but `WEXITSTATUS(n)` lets me see the real return value .

Answer (score 2):

From the man pages for `system` we can see that:

> The value returned is -1 on error (e.g.  fork(2) failed), and the
>   return status of the command otherwise.  This latter return status is
>   in the format specified in wait(2).  Thus, the exit code of the
>   command will be WEXITSTATUS(status).

This means that `system` returns a status number which needs to be "interpreted" to be able to get the return value of the program.

So, you can do the following on your second program to get the value you want:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int status = system("/home/M435TR0x/a.out");
if (WIFEXITED(status)){
   if (WEXITSTATUS == 1) printf("you answered yes\n");
   else printf("you answered no");
}
```

the WIFEXITED(status) macro tells you whether the first program exited normally, and if it did, the WEXITSTATUS(statuc) macro gives you the return value.

Disclaimer: I have not ran this code, there could be some mistakes in there.